# Alternative to routes.IgnoreRoute in Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, routes, elmah, asp.net-routing

I use asp.net c# using Web Forms.

I use Routing for my website.

I need my Route ignore ELMAH (myFolder/elmah.axd)

I was thinking to use

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

But `IgnoreRoute` is from System.Web.Mvc namescape so I cannot use it in my `Web Form` application.

- What is the equivalent for routes.IgnoreRoute in  `Web Form`?
- I want to exclude just elmah.axd from my routing, do I'm doing right?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use this for web forms:

```
routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

Good Luck!